# Firebase all images are not stored

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to store Images to firebase storage from Glide, but only the last image is being stored.

```
    for (i = 0; i < imageFileList.size(); i++) {
        StorageRef = mySTORAGE.getReferenceIMAGE_PATH + dataHolder.getTitle() + "/" + i + ".png");
        Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(imageFileList.get(i).getAbsolutePath()).into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                StorageRef.putBytes(byteArray);
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume here that `StorageRef` is a class member, since you're not showing where it's defeined.  If that's the case, your loop is overwriting `StorageRef` at each interation, and only the last value will remain after the loop finishes.  Since Glide is asynchronous, all of the callbacks will happen after the loop finishes, and they will all use the last value of `StorageRef`.

What you should do instead is make `StorageRef` a final local variable so it won't get overwritten each time through the loop:

```
final StorageReference StorageRef =
    mySTORAGE.getReferenceIMAGE_PATH + dataHolder.getTitle() + "/" + i + ".png");
```